# Variadic / optional function params in solidity ?

Tags: solidity

I didn't find a way to have optional arguments in the solidity docs so i'm wondering if anyone has found a working around to this ?

All i can think of are internal functions with " empty " params  but that's going to be ugly very fast.

As anyone found a working around to this ?

Comment: Just to clarify, what are you trying to do? Optional based on what conditions? Do you mean being able to feed in a parameter into a function which isn't used within the function?

Comment: no, i mean function x(params1,--optionalparams2,--optionalparams3,-optionalparams4) where --optionalparams is as the name says optional

Comment: @solinooby
Did you find an answer to your question bellow? If yes, please mark as answer and vote up. thanks,

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately solidity does not have the ability to add variable/ optional params. Strange enough there is away to add anonymous params, i.e. with no name.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @roland-kofler and @muhammad-altabba , Solidity does not provide for optional parameters.
Though such functionality can be achieved by using `function overloading` :  http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#function-overloading
or a hack could be sending `0x0` as the argument when not present and accounting for that within the function.
I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 4):

Till now, this is no optional parameters in Solidity.

However, they plan to include this. 
You can check the discussion at GitHub: 
https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/232