# Is it possible to make a call to contract function with varying arguments or an array List?

Tags: solidity, arrays

In C++11 we have Variadic functions that we can call with varying number of arguments. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1657930/2402577

> void myfunc( int i = 0, int j = 1, int k = 2 );
>
> ```
> // other code...
>
> myfunc();
> myfunc( 2 );
> myfunc( 2, 1 );
> myfunc( 2, 1, 0 );
> ```

I have point out that it is not possible, instead could we just sent an array list into the function, and embedded arguments into the list:

```
function foo(uint hello[]){
     uint x = hello[hello.len];
     return x + 1;
}
```

**[Q]** Is it possible to make something similar inside Solidity with an array-list[] as an argument to the function?

Answer (score -2):

No this is not possible for now.
The same question was asked here :

[Variadic Functions in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6773/variadic-optional-function-params-in-solidity)

Comment: Hi there. If you think a question has already been asked before, then flag it as a duplicate. That way it prevents other people potentially wasting their time creating and writing duplicated answers. (To flag: Close -> Duplicate of -> <paste the URL of previous question>)

Comment: I am sorry my bad. Should I assume is it possible to send a list array[] to the function than? since we can return from a function call as array[]? I have combined my question with that. The duplicate Q was asked on 2016 so I wanted to double check for an update. @RichardHorrocks

Comment: Oh sorry, I would have done it but I thought I didn't have the required permissions to mark is a duplicate.